# How do I get the message using Office.js in a react add-in

Tags: outlook, add-in

I am building a new react Outlook add-in and need to be able to download the current email.

The Office.js API has the getFileAsync method off the Office.context.document object but not the Office.context.mailbox.item object.

also as a requirement this needs to work in both Office online and local installs of Outlook.

In the existing com add-in I had direct access to the mail item.

Here is the code that I currently have to call into the API, but this only retrieves metadata.

```js
/*
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api#get-the-item-id
  */
  public getMessageViaRest = () => {
    const context: Office.AsyncContextOptions & { isRest: boolean } = {
      isRest: true
    };

    Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(context, (tokenResults) => {
      if (tokenResults.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        this.setState({ error: 'Failed to get rest api auth token' });
        return;
      }

      const apiId: string = Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, 'v2.0');
      const apiUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + '/v2.0/me/messages/' + apiId;

      try {
        fetch(apiUrl, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokenResults.value
          })
        }).then((response) => {
          response.json().then((body) => {
            for (const key in body) {
              this.state.details.push({ name: key, value: JSON.stringify(body[key]) });
            }
            this.forceUpdate();
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        this.setState({ error: JSON.stringify(error) });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfect but the REST Api does have an end point that will return the file's EML contents.

```js
public downloadViaRest = () => {
    const context: Office.AsyncContextOptions & { isRest: boolean } = {
      isRest: true
    };

    Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(context, (tokenResults) => {
      if (tokenResults.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        this.setState({ error: 'Failed to get rest api auth token' });
        return;
      }

      const apiId: string = Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, 'v2.0');
      const apiUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + '/v2.0/me/messages/' + apiId + '/$value';

      try {
        fetch(apiUrl, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokenResults.value
          })
        }).then((response) => {
          response.blob().then((blob) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'Message.eml';
            a.click();
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Rest URL is only available in the Mailbox set 1.5.